# Making a circuit entirely with XOR 2-input gates

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

The equation is

g = a'b'c + abc + ab'c' + a'bc'

and I try to make it all work in a circuit with only XOR-2 gates

so the truth table looks like this:

[image]

by working on the equation and applying De Morgan's law:

g = (a'b'c + abc + ab'c' + a'bc')'
  = ((a'b'c)' (abc)' (ab'c')' (a'bc'))'

I hit a dead end.

is there something I'm missing from boolean algebra or is it impossible to design this entirely with XOR gates?

Comment: It isn't surprising. You cannot create arbitrary logic using only XOR gates. Use NAND or NOR gates instead.

Comment: @DaveTweed I think it might be possible, just tricky. I'm just a bit confused about how to make XOR gates work like NANDs

Comment: @Coursal Nope, it simply can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actally, it is very simple:

f = (y XOR z) XOR x

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcpDfm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This just by looking at the thruth table and realzing that the bottom half is the inverse of thetop half.

---

Here's the math using boolean calculus.

We know x ^ y = x'y + xy' (^ is the XOR operator). Then:

```
g = a'b'c + abc + ab'c' + a'bc'
g = (a'b' + ab)c + (ab' + a'b)c'
     ^using a for X and b' for Y
g = (a ^ b')c + (a ^ b)c'
```

Now we have (a ^ b')  and (a ^ b), which may seem not be possible to match, unless you realise that due to the nature of the XOR, (a ^ b') = (a ^ b)' [I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader]. Thus

```
g = (a ^ b)'c + (a ^ b)c'
g = (a ^ b) ^ c
```

This is only possible due to the special nature of the original equation. If you need an AND or OR you will find it impossible to reduce the function like this.

Comment: I'm aware of this design of XOR's, but how am I going to turn the equation using this?                                                                                        **update** is this the A XOR B = A'B + AB' function?

Comment: You're confusing me. You asked if it was impossible to design this only with XOR gates. Clearly that IS possible. You already have a formula expressed in ANDs and ORs; do you want it to be expressed in XORs? That's unusual...

Comment: yes, A XOR B is equivalent to A'B + AB'. You can use parenthesis () like regular math as well.

Comment: I'm deeply sorry, I'm new to this kind of field and I only knew about this xor equivalent trick for two variables